# forms.timer not triggering the function on form load function

Tags: c#, winforms

I have following code in the form_Load function

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer newtimer = new Timer();
newtimer.Tick += new EventHandler(refreshinfo);
newtimer.Start();
newtimer.Interval = 20000;
```

The "refreshinfo" function goes like this:

```
private void refreshinfo(object source,EventArgs e)
{
       // Some code here
}
```

The function "refreshinfo" is called after the 20 seconds. So far so good. Problem is that i want "refreshinfo" to be called on form_Load event also. So that i can get the desired results from "refreshinfo" when the user loads this form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Invoke it after 20 seconds
    Timer newtimer = new Timer();
    newtimer.Tick += refreshinfo;
    newtimer.Interval = 20000;
    newtimer.Start();

    // Invoke it now
    refreshinfo(sender, e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just trigger the refreshinfo() function in the Form_Load function?

Answer (score 0):

Just run it in  form_Load

```
Thread thrd = new Thread(() => { refreshinfo(null, null); });
thrd.Start();
```